# Prove $\max_X tr(X^TAX) = $ k largest eigenvalues of $A$ for real, symmetric $A$ and $X^TX=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I know how to prove this if $X$ is a vector (eigendecomposition with orthogonal eigenvectors, picking the largest eigenvalue), but I'm not sure how to proceed if $X$ is a matrix. Say, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. The book I'm reading suggests a proof by induction, but I don't know how the induction step would work here.

Comment: What is the $\max$ taken over? $X$? If so, you can take $A$ to be diagonal.

Comment: Yes, the $\max$ is over $X$. I see why that's true, but I'm not sure how to prove this even in the case where $A$ is diagonal (even though it's intuitively obvious).

Comment: $k$ can be anything in $1 \leq k \leq n$

Comment: A remark: trace operator is invariant to cyclic permutation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)). Therefore you problem can be written under the equivalent form $max tr(XX^TA)$ which is the dot product of $XX^T$ and $A^T=A$. Thus (ideally) maximized when $XX^T$ is proportionnal to $A$. But how to take into account the constraint $X^TX=I$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is more convenient to write as $\operatorname{tr} (Y AY^T)$ where $Y Y^T = I$.

Since $A$ is symmetric we can write $Q^T A Q = \Lambda$ for some orthogonal $Q$ 
and diagonal $\Lambda$. If $P$ is a permutation matrix, then we have
$P^T Q^T A Q P = P^T \Lambda P$. This is a diagonal matrix whose entries (the
eigenvalues of $A$) are
permuted by $P$.

Note that $Y P^T Q^T Q P Y = I$, hence we can write
$\max_{Y Y^T =I} \operatorname{tr} (Y AY^T) = \max_{Y Y^T =I, P \text{ permutation}} \operatorname{tr} (Y  P^T \Lambda P Y^T)$

We can write $YP^T \Lambda PY^T = \sum_{i=1}^k [P^T\Lambda P]_{ii} Y_i Y_i^T$, where $Y_i$ is the $i$th column of $Y$, and
$\operatorname{tr} (Y P^T \Lambda P Y^T) =  \sum_{i=1}^k [P^T \Lambda P]_{ii} \operatorname{tr}  ( Y_i Y_i^T ) = \sum_{i=1}^k [P^T \Lambda P]_{ii} \operatorname{tr}  ( Y_i^T Y_i  ) =\sum_{i=1}^k [P^T \Lambda P]_{ii} $.

In particular, if the sum of the $k$ largest eigenvalues is $S$, we see that
$\operatorname{tr} (Y AY^T) \le S$ and if we choose $P$ appropriately we get equality.